# Does the SaxParser detect xml encoding?

Tags: java, android, html, xml, saxparser

I have an html file that contains these tags at the top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="fi" lang="fi" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
```

An exception is occuring when i try to use a SaxParser to parse the Html file saying that some character at a specified line and column is invalid when i use this code:

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
InputSource is = new InputSource(new FileInputStream(file));  
parser.parse(is, this);
```

if i specify the encoding with this: `is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");`
, the exception does not occur.

Why do i have to explicitly tell the SaxParser which encoding it should use? can't the SaxParser detect the encoding from the bytestream or the tag in the beginning of the html file?

Also, the docs say:

"If there is no character stream, but there is
  a byte stream, the parser will use that byte stream, using the
  encoding specified in the InputSource or else (if no encoding is
  specified) autodetecting the character encoding using an algorithm
  such as the one in the XML specification"

But this is not true! Looking further in the java code i see this:

```
 /*
     * TODO: Let Expat try to guess the encoding instead of defaulting.
     * Unfortunately, I don't know how to tell which encoding Expat picked,
     * so I won't know how to encode "<externalEntity>" below. The solution
     * I think is to fix Expat to not require the "<externalEntity>"
     * workaround.
     */
    this.encoding = encoding == null ? DEFAULT_ENCODING : encoding;
    this.pointer = initialize(
        this.encoding,
        processNamespaces
    );
```

Is there no algorithm for detecting xml encoding?

Comment: There are many SAX parsers. Which one are you talking about? What code base does that TODO comment come from? Also: why are you using iso-8859-1 when the file says it is Windows-1252?

Comment: it crashes when i use "Cp1252" or "windows-1252"

Comment: and i'm talking about the javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser. I tested this api in a whole new project. Just opening an xml file that contains the windows-1252 prolog and the letter ä in a simple root tag. It throws an exception "not well-formed". I think the SaxParser on android is broken

Comment: SAXParser is an interface, there are many implementations of this interface. You tagged the question "android", I suppose we should therefore have guessed that you are using the default implementation of the SAXParser interface on the android platform -- but it helps not to leave us guessing!

Comment: Sorry about that. I made a sample to isolate the saxparser and did a test. It seems like saxparser does not seem able to recognize windows-1252. Check this out please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715449/saxparser-not-well-formed-invalid-token

Comment: I can well understand that implementors of a parser on Android would choose not to support a Microsoft-proprietary character encoding. Certainly, the XML specification doesn't require such encodings to be supported.

Comment: Seems like the XmlPullParser is able to recognize encodings. I guess i'm going to have to refactor everything. Seems really weird though that SaxParser can't because it should work according to the documentation. I hope i will find out someday why it doesn't work